# Spring security and() function

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security, authorization

Can you please explain in a simple way for what reason we need to use ***and()*** method in HttpSecurity.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("Employee", "Manager", "HR")
            .antMatchers("/hr_info").hasRole("HR")
            .antMatchers("/manager_info/**").hasRole("Manager")
            .and().formLogin().permitAll();
}
```

Comment: I will add that as of Spring Security 5.2, you no longer need to use the `and()` function in the security DSL and instead can use lambdas. See this blog post for more details https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring security [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/html5/#jc-httpsecurity) explains it as follows.

> The Java Configuration equivalent of closing an XML tag is expressed
> using the and() method which allows us to continue configuring the
> parent. If you read the code it also makes sense. I want to configure
> authorized requests and configure form login and configure HTTP Basic
> authentication.

**Accordingly**, you say the following with your own settings:

- Ensures that any request to our application requires the user to be authenticated,
- Allows authentication for some links only to the specified role,
- Allows users to authenticate with form based login.